# Mocked private method is called instead of being mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm using PowerMockito for mocking private method. But instead being mocked it is called. I need to test strangeMethod(), which calls privateMethod().

Here is my class for testing:

```
public class ExampleService {
    public String strangeMethod() {
        privateMethod();
        return "Done!";
    }

    private String privateMethod() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

My test method:

```
@Test
public void strangeMethodTest() throws Exception {
    ExampleService exampleService = PowerMockito.spy(new ExampleService());
    PowerMockito.when(exampleService, "privateMethod").thenReturn("");
    exampleService.strangeMethod();
}
```

As a result of the test I'm getting UnsupportedOperationException. This means, that privateMethod() is called.

Comment: Are you sure you need this in the first place? This seems pretty dirty, a method is private for a reason.

Comment: Try annotating your test class with `@PrepareForTest({ExampleService .class})` and `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `PowerMockito.spy(new ExampleService());` all method calls at first will be delegated to instance of real class. What's why you get `UnsupportedOperationException` at line:

`PowerMockito.when(exampleService, "privateMethod").thenReturn("");`

If you want to avoid calling real method, then use `PowerMockito.mock( ExampleService.class);` and `doCallRealMethod`/`thenCallRealMethod` for method which shouldn't be mocked.

This example is show that private method is mocked:

Class:

```
public class ExampleService {
    public String strangeMethod() {

        return privateMethod();
    }

    private String privateMethod() {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@PrepareForTest(ExampleService.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestPrivate {

    @Test
    public void strangeMethodTest() throws Exception {
        ExampleService exampleService = PowerMockito.spy(new ExampleService());
        PowerMockito.when(exampleService, "privateMethod").thenReturn("a");
        String actual = exampleService.strangeMethod();

        assertEquals("a",actual);
    }

}
```

Comment: My example still use 'spy'. So real method still is called once, when it's mocked. As I mentioned above, you need use 'PowerMockito.mock' to avoid real method call.

Comment: But if I mock my exampleService object, how can I test that method returns "Done!"?

Comment: Use doCallRealMethod or thenCallRealMethod for 'strangeMethod'. Example: 'PowerMockito.when(exampleService.strangeMethod()).thenCallRealMethod()'. I'm sorry, I'm from my mobile phone, so methods names could be a bit incorrect or have typos.

Comment: But I have to aware you that it's a really dirty solution and should be used carefully to cover old, legacy code. But it never ever should be used to test/write new code.